# EF Core 5: Temporal table update deadlocks with subsequent stored procedure call accessing that table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, database-deadlocks

Our application experiences occasional deadlocks when updating a record in a temporal table and then invoking a stored procedure that accesses that table in a temporal way.

The application is using EF Core 5 against SQL Server database and still runs on .NET Core 3.1.

The logic first updates the record, then invokes `Update` on its `DbContext` and then awaits a call to `SaveChangesAsync` on the same `DbContext`. Then the stored procedure accessing that table is invoked using `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync`.

Based on database logging, it appears that both the save and the stored procedure are invoked in the same process, though it was expected that `await` on the save would ensure completion before the stored procedure is invoked.

This issue could not be reproduced in test environment.

Question: How can such deadlocks happen if all calls are awaited?

Comment: Deadlocks are a feature of pessimistic concurrency in the database between two different queries, nothing to do with `await`. For help with a deeadlock, we need to see *all* of the following: the queries involved (generated SQL in the case of EF), the query plans (share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan), the relevant table *and index* DDL definitions, and most importantly the deadlock XML. The question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: @Charlieface, I was looking for general guidance on how such logic should be written. The assumption regarding `await` above was that `await`ed calls would be invoked serially, completing each call prior to proceeding to the next call. Based on the deadlock XML, however, it appears that they are not. Hence, I was seeking clarification/guidance. Providing the information you requested may not be possible due to it being proprietary.

Comment: No they would be executed serially (the same DbContext cannot be used multithreaded anyway). Therefore is another query elsewhere that is deadlocking against it. Without the information I asked this question is not answerable. You can anonymize it if you want, use SentryOne Plan Explorer to anonymize the query plan.